# R function that looks through previous dates

Tags: r, time-series, grouping, rank

I have some weekly data slices that have a name, date, and a rank.

I would like to create a new column to flag when they are consistently ranked 2 or higher in the two previous periods.

```
  name<-  c("a","a","a","a",
         "b","b","b","b",
         "c","c","c","c")     
  date<-  c("2015-01-19","2014-01-12","2014-01-05","2014-01-01",
            "2015-01-19","2014-01-12","2014-01-05","2014-01-01",
            "2015-01-19","2014-01-12","2014-01-05","2014-01-01")
  rank<-  c(1,2,1,3,
            2,3,2,1,
            3,1,3,2)
  df<-data.frame(name,date,rank)
  df<-arrange(df,date,desc(rank))
  df
    name       date rank
     a 2014-01-01    3
     c 2014-01-01    2
     b 2014-01-01    1
     c 2014-01-05    3
     b 2014-01-05    2
     a 2014-01-05    1
     b 2014-01-12    3
     a 2014-01-12    2
     c 2014-01-12    1
     c 2015-01-19    3
     b 2015-01-19    2
     a 2015-01-19    1
```

For example: 
For a on Jan 19, it was ranked 1 and it was also ranked less than 2 on both Jan 12, and Jan 5, so flag this with a 1
For b on Jan 19, it was ranked 2, but it was not ranked less than 2 on both previous dates, and therefore, flag with a 0.
For c on Jan 19, it was not ranked less than 2, so flag with 0.

Here's the output I'd like to see:

```
name  date  rank    consistent
    a   1/1/2014    3   NA
    c   1/1/2014    2   NA
    b   1/1/2014    1   NA
    c   1/5/2014    3   NA
    b   1/5/2014    2   NA
    a   1/5/2014    1   NA
    b   1/12/2014   3   0
    a   1/12/2014   2   0
    c   1/12/2014   1   0
    c   1/19/2015   3   0
    b   1/19/2015   2   0
    a   1/19/2015   1   1
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a `data.table`-based solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[,consistent:=rank < 3 & c(NA,rank[-.N])<3 & c(NA,NA,rank[-c(.N-1,.N)])<3,name]
d
#     name       date rank consistent
#  1:    a 2014-01-01    3      FALSE
#  2:    c 2014-01-01    2         NA
#  3:    b 2014-01-01    1         NA
#  4:    c 2014-01-05    3      FALSE
#  5:    b 2014-01-05    2         NA
#  6:    a 2014-01-05    1      FALSE
#  7:    b 2014-01-12    3      FALSE
#  8:    a 2014-01-12    2      FALSE
#  9:    c 2014-01-12    1      FALSE
# 10:    c 2015-01-19    3      FALSE
# 11:    b 2015-01-19    2      FALSE
# 12:    a 2015-01-19    1       TRUE
```

It does not produce the `consistent` column exactly as in the sample output, but makes the job flagging the requested rows.

**UPDATE**

Here is the updated solution that produces output consistent with the one in the OP's question:

```
setDT(d)[,consistent:=rowSums(cbind(rank < 3, c(NA,rank[-.N])<3, c(NA,NA,rank[-c(.N-1,.N)])<3)) %/%3 ,name]

print(d)
#     name       date rank consistent
#  1:    a 2014-01-01    3         NA
#  2:    c 2014-01-01    2         NA
#  3:    b 2014-01-01    1         NA
#  4:    c 2014-01-05    3         NA
#  5:    b 2014-01-05    2         NA
#  6:    a 2014-01-05    1         NA
#  7:    b 2014-01-12    3          0
#  8:    a 2014-01-12    2          0
#  9:    c 2014-01-12    1          0
# 10:    c 2015-01-19    3          0
# 11:    b 2015-01-19    2          0
# 12:    a 2015-01-19    1          1
```

Comment: Hello Marat, this is really helpful and simple, thank you.  May I ask, if it doesn't exist in the date?  Do you think it would be able to detect that it was missing in the previous date and then assign it 0?

Comment: you mean that the rank column might contain NAs?

Comment: Thanks Marat.  I thjnk this is a new request and will post it in a new thread if i cannot find the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but maybe you need something like this?:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(consistent = rank > lag(rank, 1) & rank > lag(rank, 2))
Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
Groups: name

   name       date rank consistent
1     a 2014-01-01    3         NA
2     c 2014-01-01    2         NA
3     b 2014-01-01    1         NA
4     c 2014-01-05    3         NA
5     b 2014-01-05    2      FALSE
6     a 2014-01-05    1      FALSE
7     b 2014-01-12    3       TRUE
8     a 2014-01-12    2      FALSE
9     c 2014-01-12    1      FALSE
10    c 2015-01-19    3       TRUE
11    b 2015-01-19    2      FALSE
12    a 2015-01-19    1      FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks RStudent.  Appreciate the feedback; I thought I was clear with the example but apparently not!  I get this error running your example ': Error in UseMethod("groups") : 
  no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "function". '

Comment: Would you like to compare the `rank` value for each `name` so that if both previous values were less that 2 flag it with a 1/TRUE, otherwise with 0/FALSE? Which version is you `dplyr`?